# Creation Date and File.Copy Issue

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am trying to copy files from one directory to another and test based upon the file creation date.

```
File.Copy(fileName, directory + fileNameOnly, true);
```

The problem occurs later in my program when I checked the creation date to ensure it is no more than 5 days old.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
if (file.CreationTime.AddHours(120) < DateTime.Now) {}
```

I have seen that the creation date when copied back is set to 1980-01-01. This is not useful for my requirements as I would like maintain the creation date from the original file. Is there another method of comparing the dates or is it the copy that loses the creation date value.

I guess my question is, how can I maintain the Creation Date?

Comment: That's strange. I've tried copying a file using File.Copy, and in my case the copied file gets the current date/time as its creation date/time. But... not exactly. At every run the the creation date is the same, even though that is now 5 minutes ago. Even if I copy the same file to the same target using Explorer, the copied file shows that same date/time (which by then was 6 minutes ago). It almost looks like Windows is caching the creation date or something. If I change the target folder or filename, that new file gets the actual date/time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [File.SetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime.aspx) method after you copy the file.
You can get the source file's creation time with [File.GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx)

Comment: this gives a System.Unauthorized exception for me

Comment: It seems not work from my Windows 10 local machine to a Linux NAS via SMB.