# How can I copy file with its details in C#?

Tags: c#, file, copy, file-copying

I'm trying copy file from one location to another but when I do it with the Copy function

```
System.IO.File.Copy(OldFilePath, NewFilePath, true);
```

The file details like the creation date, modified date, accessed date and etc are not copied with the file.
How can I copy the file with the file's details?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4452896/1997232) helpful?

Comment: The file properties, all the details in the: Right click on file --> Properties.
Like creation date and etc...

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I can use it when I copy one file, but when I copy 1 million files it would take tons of time to change each one of their creation date @Sinatr

Comment: But you are creating new files - of course the creation date and access will be now! so you will have to reset them by hand

Comment: *When I copy 1 million files it would take tons of time to change each one of their creation date* - this is unavoidable. Maybe you want to **move** files instead (attributes will persist afaik)?

Comment: @BugFinder That's what I'm trying to understand, how can I copy them with their details.

Comment: @Sinatr I want the files to be also in their original location and copy them to the new location.

Comment: You cant copy them with - you are making a "new" copy - you to make the new copy and then set the details the same.

Comment: It will take __some__  extra time, but not nearly as much as copying the data itself..!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following instructions after the Copy instruction will update some DateTime attributes:

```
System.IO.File.SetCreationTime  (NewFilePath, System.IO.File.GetCreationTime  (OldFilePath));
System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTime(NewFilePath, System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(OldFilePath));
System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime (NewFilePath, System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime (OldFilePath));
```